Flip a coin $n$ times, but stop when you get heads. Are the flips independent?
Here's a problem I came up with while playing Dyson Sphere Program.

You plan to flip a coin $n$ times, but if you get heads you stop flipping. What is the probability you get $n$ tails?

The part of this problem that confuses me is the idea of stopping when you get heads. I understand that if you flip a coin $n$ times then $P(n\text{ tails}) = P(\text{tails})^n$ because each flip is an independent event.
However, when I try to intuit the results of my question, the results are different. I believe this is because the coin flips in my problem are not independent. After all, if flip 1 is heads, flip 2 doesn't even happen. Let's say $n=2$. There are three possible outcomes:

The first flip is heads, and we stop flipping.
The first flip is tails, and the second is heads.
Both flips are tails.

In one of the three outcomes, we've gotten all tails. This suggests the probability is $\frac 13$.
When I try to use an equation, I get a different result. The intersection of dependent events says
$$P(\text{1$^{st}$ tails}\cap\text{2$^{nd}$ tails})=P(\text{1$^{st}$ tails})*P(\text{2$^{nd}$ tails}|\text{1$^{st}$ tails})$$
$$0.25*0.25=0.5$$
This is the same result as if the flips were independent.
Which of these methods is the correct one to use for this problem? What am I thinking about wrong here?

The inspiration for this question is the "fractionator" building in Dyson Sphere Program. You feed it a conveyer belt of hydrogen, and each fractionator has a 1% chance of turning one unit of hydrogen into deuterium (using up the hydrogen in the process). I'm trying to work out the probability of turning one unit of hydrogen into deuterium given $n$ fractionators in a row. The analogy of an unfair coin seemed appropriate. I'm starting with a fair coin since it is easier to intuit.

The flips are still independent , but the game is different and therefore the probability for a success.

In your initial analysis, the probabilities are not 1/3 each, because the events have different probabilities: the probability for event 1 (heads on first flip) is 0.5; the other events have probability 0.25. Your second approach is on target.

A way to display this process is with a tree.  Each node is a flip, each child is an outcome, and the edges leaving the node for the children are labelled with the probability of that flip producing that outcome (0.5/0.5 here).  In your tree, the root node has a "T" child and a "H" terminal.  That "T" child has a "T" child and a "H" terminal and so on to $n$ nodes and a "T" terminal ($n$ edges = $n$ "T"s from the root).  The dependence of number of flips on previous flip results is encoded in the tree.  The probability of a terminal is the product of the edges from the root to that terminal.
